# jQuery Validation Plugin: "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" noSpace

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

New to the jQuery validation plugin and can't figure out this TypeError:

Here is my html:

```
<input name="clusterName" type="text" id="clusterName" />
```

Here are the relevant pieces of my jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cloudBuilderForm').validate({

    rules: {
        clusterName: {
            required: true,
            noSpace: true
        },
        keyPair: {
            required: true,
            noSpace: true
        },
        volumeSize: {
            required: true,
            range:[256, 1024]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        clusterName: {
            required: "Provide cluster name",
            noSpace: "Cannot contain spaces"
        },
        keyPair: {
            required: "Provide valid key-pair",
            noSpace: "Cannot contain spaces"
        },
        volumeSize: {
            required: "Provide a volume size",
            range: "Must be between 256 & 1024"
        }
    },

    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).siblings('span').hide();
    }

    });

    $('#cloudBuilderSubmit').click(function() {
        $('#cloudBuilderForm').valid();
    });
});
```

I've also included

```
jquery.validate.min.js
additional-methods.min.js
```

in that order

Here is the full error:

```
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element clusterName, check the 'noSpace' method.
```

Comment: jQuery Validation Engine is not the same plugin.  Edited tags.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Going to leave this up for others that might find it. Googling told me to use the "noSpace" rule. In reality the rule is "nowhitespace". Hope this helps others